# AngularJS Подстановка имени в ссылку

Tags: angularjs

Контроллер:

```
$http.get('http://site.com/file/filename/'+id)
    .then(function success(response) {
    $scope.link = 'site.ru/file/название_файла';
    });
```

GET запрос возвращает:

```
[{"filename":"2017-10-10_14.jpg"}]
```

помогите сформировать ссылку вида:

```
site.ru/file/2017-10-10_14.jpg
```

Comment: `$scope.link = 'site.ru/file/' + response[0].filename;` ?

Comment: У меня выдаёт ошибку: TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined. В чём по Вашему дело?

Comment: у Вас значение `response` совпадает с `[{"filename":"2017-10-10_14.jpg"}]`?

Comment: Я немного растерян. Не подскажите, как это лечится?)

Comment: Какое значение у Вас возвращается в `response`?

Comment: console.log(response.data) => 
{filename: "2017-10-10_14.09.55.669_af23e4"}

Comment: Тогда все проще. `$scope.link = 'site.ru/file/' + response.data.filename;`

Comment: Скажите, а если необходимо вывести массив файлов? Такой метод тоже актуален?

Comment: Нет, здесь Вам уже нужно, например, использовать метод forEach(). Прочитать можно здесь: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach. В итоге у Вас получится что-то типа response.data.forEach(function () { тут какая то логика });

Comment: Спасибо за совет!